# Текст парсинг

Tags: xml, sax, java

Здравствуйте,

не могли бы посоветовать, как можно сделать, чтоб при парсинге тектового файла с помощью SAX и JAXP в xml файл, атрибут id элемента пронумеровывался? Можно ли такое сделать? Пример: `<document>
<el id="1"><text>Motivationsschreiben.</text></el>
<el id="2"><text>Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren.</text></el> </document>`

Спасибо

Comment: имеете ввиду чтобы id генерировался автоматически?

Comment: да, если возможно. Т.е у каж el есть атрибут id, только без номера, вот жоно ли как то сделать чтоб и нумерация выполнялась?

Comment: ну вы заведите переменную которую инкрементируйте при каждом создании атрибута id и присваивайте этому атрибуту значение этой переменной.

Comment: ясно, спс.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

заведите переменную которую инкрементируйте при каждом создании атрибута id и присваивайте этому атрибуту значение этой переменной.